# php - How to replace a char from each word starting from a certain position in each word

Tags: php, string, replace, cpu-word, each

How can I replace a char from each word of a string starting from a certain position in each word?

For example:

```
$string = "one twone trone fourone nourone";<br />
// I want to replace each n with X starting from second position in each word.<br />
// Last word has n on first position and should remain there.<br />
$new_string = "oXe twoXe troXe fouroXe nouroXe";
```

Comment: You can check the use of `str_replace`, `str_ireplace`, `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what's considered first `n` here. One possible approach:

```
$string = "one twone trone fourone nourone";
$new_string = preg_replace('/\Bn/', 'X', $string);
// string(31) "oXe twoXe troXe fouroXe nouroXe";
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/170498). As you see, regex replacement function is used ([**preg_replace**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)); the pattern `/\Bn` is described as 'match all `n` symbols that are not preceded by word boundary' (= 'are not at the beginning of the words').

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I want to replace all chars starting from second position in each word.. so I need to replace all chars not only the first occurrence.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work when you apply this solution? I.e., can you give an input sample, and an output you want (but don't get with the code)?

Comment: I try to use it with diacritics like Ă and ă. I try replacing Ă with ă in "ĂĂĂononĂ nonĂĂnĂĂ" and I get "ăăăononĂ nonĂănĂă" .. instead of "Ăăăononă nonăănăă". Maybe problem for using diacritics ?

Comment: @AlexTz Works fine [here](https://eval.in/170519). Note the difference (`/u` regex modifier).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. Maybe not the best way but it works fine:

$string = 'ĂĂĂononĂ nonĂĂnĂĂ';

$string = explode(' ', $string);
   $string_output = "";

foreach ($string as $s) {
     $first_letter = substr($s,0,1);
     $remaining_letters = substr($s,1,25);
     $remaining_letters = str_replace("Ă","ă", $remaining_letters);
     $s = $first_letter.$remaining_letters;
     $string_output .= $s." ";
   }
   $string = $string_output;

Comment: *note: this will add an extra space after the string.